# Setting different default views to modern list and web part and modifying the "See all" link URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, list-view, modern-experience

I know I can set a view for modern list web part in the settings of that web part and then I can also browse manually to the list itself and make a different view as the default view there. The problem is that if a user clicks the "See all" link, he/she will be taken to the list with the same view that was applied on the web part instead of the full/default list view.

In my case the scenario is that I want to show all items on the full list itself and only 12 items on the web part. I applied the custom view for the web part so that it only shows 12 newest items and if a user then clicks the "See all" link, he/she will see the list but only those 12 newest items and not all. This is because the "See all" link seems to have the web part view's id in the URL.

Am I missing something or is this really how it's designed? Is there anything to be done so that I could have the custom view on the web part but still have the full list/view open via the "See all" link?

I hope my explanation/description of the problem was not confusing. If that's the case, I of course will try my best to clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it is designed in SharePoint online list web part.

The [see all](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/11/18/show-hide-see-all-link-from-sharepoint-list-library-web-parts/) link will redirect to the list view selected in list web part settings:

[image]

Out of the box, there are no options to change the hyperlink of see all link. Only option available is to [hide the see all link from web part](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/11/18/show-hide-see-all-link-from-sharepoint-list-library-web-parts/)

---

**Workaround**:

You can install SPFx [react script editor](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor) in your site, add the modern script editor web part on your modern page to change the URL of "see all" link using JavaScript & DOM manipulation.

You can use code like:

```
document.querySelector("a[aria-label='See all Content Scheduler']").href = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/wlive/Lists/ContentScheduler?viewid=711efefa%2D821c%2D492f%2D8e22%2D1ba097f908bf"
```

Use actual `aria-label` value on your page (instead of 'See all Content Scheduler') by inspecting the "see all" link.

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was afraid it's not possible OOTB, which seems really weird to me. I will consider your Script Editor trick also. :)